# How to open folder selection dialog in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using PickSingleFolderAsync() to select a folder.
But folder dialog look like file selection dialog.
Here is my code.

```
private async void OpenFolder_Clicked()
{
    var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker
    {
        SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop
    };
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    if (folder != null)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Here is result of above code:

[image]

My expectation:
How to open below folder selection dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The second image seems to be a dialog created by `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` on .NET Framework which internally calls [SHBrowseForFolderW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shbrowseforfolderw). You don't have access to both APIs from UWP.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible if I create a custom browser dialog like that?

Comment: I think it would require a lot of coding but you can try.